# MI A3 DPI issue

Tags: xiaomi, android-10, android-one

I recently got a new phone, a Xiaomi Mi A3 that runs android one (10). The default DPI is "too big", so I changed the DPI from the developer settings from the default one (380 IIRC) to 411 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6dF6.png). But now, I'm having an issue. When I lock my phone, and unlock it, after pressing the power button, or the volume button, the icons will be too big, just like on the screenshot above. Sometimes, the battery indicators font changes too, and becomes very big. I found a forum post on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a3/help/how-to-definitely-change-dpi-t4132467/amp/) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MiA3/comments/gppf9l/ui_elements_size_is_mixed_between_small_and/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=post_body), and they have the same issue with me. Is this a bug/issue with the phone, or android 10? Is there anything I can do? Any solution? Maybe ADB can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following options :

1. Disabling your fingerprint will solve the issue (permanent fix ).
2. resetting your DPI to 480 will fix this issue (sometimes works).
3. you can just turn on and off dark mode will fix this for some time.
4. Reset your phone and don't mess with DPI ever (don't do this).
5. Get a custom ROM or a new phone.

Comment: I installed a custom rom. I finally got rid of all these weird bugs